# Associativity of Fundamental group

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Let $X$ be topological space. Let $f,g$ and $h$ be paths in $X$ such that terminal point of $f$ is same as initial point of $g$ and terminal point of $g$ is same as initial point of $h$. I need to show that the paths $f\ast(g\ast h)$ and $(f\ast g)\ast h$ are path homotopic and I know exactly what path homotopy works here. My question is isn’t it obvious that these two paths are same? And path homotopy is a reflexive relation then why we need a path homotopy (non-trivial) to show that these two paths are path homotopic.

If there are paths such that $f\ast(g\ast h)$ is not same as $(f\ast g)\ast h$, help me finding such paths.

Comment: SO you have a $\frac12 ,\frac14 ,\frac14$ or $\frac14 ,\frac14 ,\frac12$ partition of the $[0,1]$ in the path for the composite path and that needs some work to justify.

Comment: The paths have the same *trace* (image) but travel at different speeds, and are technically different functions. Both can be reparametrised with suitable speed so that they run according to a $[0,1/3],[1/3,2/3],[2/3,1]$ partition **up to homotopy**, so define the same homotopy class which equals what is perhaps the most natural definition of a triple composition $f\cdot g\cdot h$.

Answer (score 0):

Given a topological space $X$ and $a,b\in X$, we denote with $\Omega(X,a,b)$ the set of the paths in $X$ that go from $a$ to $b$. If $\alpha\in\Omega(X,a,b),\:\beta\in\Omega(X,b,c)$ and $\gamma\in\Omega(X,c,d)$, then $(\alpha\ast \beta)\ast \gamma$ is always path homotopic to $\alpha\ast(\beta\ast\gamma)$.

Let's prove this fact. Remember that, by definition, we have that:
$$((\alpha\ast \beta)\ast \gamma)(t)=\begin{cases}\alpha(4t)\qquad\qquad t\in\left[0,\frac{1}{4}\right]\\\beta(4t-1)\qquad\:t\in\left[\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{2}\right]\\\gamma(2t-1)\qquad\:t\in\left[\frac{1}{2},1\right]\end{cases}$$
while:
$$(\alpha\ast (\beta\ast \gamma))(t)=\begin{cases}\alpha(2t)\qquad\qquad t\in\left[0,\frac{1}{2}\right]\\\beta(4t-2)\qquad\:t\in\left[\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{4}\right]\\\gamma(4t-3)\qquad\:t\in\left[\frac{3}{4},1\right]\end{cases}$$
The two paths differ from a reparametrization of the unit interval $I:=[0,1]$, which is defined in the following way: $$\phi:I\to I,\quad \phi(t)=\begin{cases}2t\qquad\qquad t\in\left[0,\frac{1}{4}\right]\\t+\frac{1}{4}\qquad\:\: t\in\left[\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{2}\right]\\\frac{t+1}{2}\qquad\quad\:t\in\left[\frac{1}{2},1\right]\end{cases}$$
Just nothe that $\phi$ is well defined, continuous, $\phi(0)=0$, $\phi(1)=1$ and $$(\alpha\ast(\beta\ast\gamma))(\phi(t))=((\alpha\ast\beta)\ast\gamma)(t)$$
Consider: $$H:I\times I\to X,\quad H(s,t):=(\alpha\ast (\beta\ast\gamma))(s\phi(t)+(1-s)t)$$
The function $H$ is an homtopy between: $$H(0,t)=(\alpha\ast(\beta\ast\gamma))(t)$$ and $$H(1,t)=(\alpha\ast(\beta\ast\gamma))(\phi(t))=((\alpha\ast\beta)\ast\gamma)(t)$$

Answer (score 0):

$(f*(g*h))(1/2) = f(1) = g(0)$ whereas $((f*g)*h)(1/2) = g(1)=h(0)$.

So, in the special (and quite possible) case that $g(0) \ne g(1)$ it follows that
$$f*(g*h) \ne (f*g)*h
$$

For an actual example, let $f(t)=t$ and $g(t)=1+t$ and $h(t)=2+t$, and note that
$$((f*g)*h)(1/2)=2 \quad\text{whereas}\quad (f*(g*h))(1/2)=1
$$
And if that does not convince you, try graphing the two functions $f*(g*h)$ and $(f*g)*h$ in this example.